# where does chromedriver get downloded when we use webdrivermanager inselenium version 4

Tags: selenium4

where does chromedriver get downloded when we use webdrivermanager inselenium version 4
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client"); // jdk

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();// github

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();// se
    // driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com");//no history, but waits
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.w3schools.com");// history is maintained, no wait
    Thread.sleep(2000);//
    driver.close();
    // driver.quit();
}
```